# What is the proper Stack Exchange site for my question about a problem with the Windows 10 drawing tools or my Wacom drawing tablet?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to fix a problem that either relates to Windows 10 drawing tools or a [Wacom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacom) drawing tablet. I am not sure which party is to blame. Is [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) the correct Stack Exchange site for this type of question or is it something else?

Since I experience an issue whether or not my tablet is on and problems persists only in Microsoft applications ([OneNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote) and Snipping tool), I would try to avoid asking questions from Wacom customer service first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is on topic on Super User - both if its a hardware or software issue.